# When hover a div, the rest of them change

Tags: jquery, css

I would like to, when I hover a '.post' div, the rest of '.post' divs change, for example its background.

How could I do this?

CSS:

```
.post { width: 25px; height: 25px; }
```

HTML:

```
<div class="post"> ... </div>
<div class="post"> ... </div>
<div class="post"> ... </div>
<div class="post"> ... </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a hover function and `.not(this)`

```
$('.post').hover(function() {
    // .css can be anything you want it to be
    $('.post').not(this).css({'color':'red'});
}, function() { // Revert back to default (optional)
    $('.post').css({'color':'black'});
});
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/PYC5z/)

Answer (score 1):

Use jquery:

```
$(function(){
  $("div.post").mouseover(function(){
    $(this).siblings().css("background-color","red");
});
$("div.post").mouseout(function(){
    $(this).siblings().css("background-color","white");
});
});
```

Comment: I think you accidentally posted a broken link.

Comment: No its correct link only u can see the answer demo there

Comment: It seems to be somewhat working now but it just goes to a login screen.  It's far better to use [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net).